# Is there a shortcut from the parish to Undead Burg in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

I've unlocked the bonfire near the blacksmith, killed the boar, and raised the portcullis. However, I'm told that there's a merchant back in Undead Burg. I went back there once, but almost didn't make it due to rat poison. Haven't made it back since. Is there a shortcut that leads back to Undead Burg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. As you come into the Parish from the Blacksmith bonfire, directly across from you will be a set of cages, these cages are an elevator that leads directly to Firelink Shrine.

[image]

Comment: Ah hahaha.  In the dreaded room with the  black Knight. Thanks!

Comment: @odinkirk the Tower Knight (big guy with the tower shield) isn't too scary, just avoid his swings and try and get around behind him. With some persistence he shouldn't be too much of a problem :)

Comment: Thanks, Ben, but I took the coward's way out and ran past.

Comment: @odinkirk it's a legitimate tactic :P

Comment: Haha oops. That's done.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the rat poison you want to avoid, the bonfire at the other end of the bridge heals all negative effects, including poison, so it's conceivable that you could just run right to that, being careful not to fall of course.